# Proof of the Multinomial Theorem Using Mathematical Induction

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I am trying to prove the following proposition:

> Suppose that $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and that $r_{1}, r_{2}, \dots, r_{n}$ are nonnegative integers such that
> \begin{equation}
> r_{1} + r_{2} + \dots + r_{n} = r \geq 0.
> \end{equation}
> Then the following relation holds:
> \begin{equation}
> \left(z_{1} + z_{2} + \dots + z_{n}\right)^{r} = \sum_{r_{1}+\dots+r_{n} = r}\frac{r!}{r_{1}!r_{2}!\dots r_{n}!}{z_{1}}^{r_{1}}{z_{2}}^{r_{2}}\dots{z_{n}}^{r_{n}}.
> \end{equation}

The case for $n = 1$ is obviously correct. The case for $n = 2$ reduces to nothing but
\begin{equation}
\left(z_{1} + z_{2}\right)^{r} = \sum_{r_{1} = 0}^{r}\binom{r}{r_{1}}{z_{1}}^{r_{1}}{z_{2}}^{r-r_{1}},
\end{equation}
which is the famous binomial formula, and can be accepted without proof. However, I am not sure how to use the induction hypothesis at $n$ to lead to the conclusion at $n+1$. Can anyone provide hints or a complete proof?

P.S. I am looking at this formula for understanding the expansion of the differential of a multivariate function.

I have come up with the proof. The proof goes as follows.

The case for $n = 1$ and $n = 2$ can be easily verified. To use mathematical induction, we assume that the formula holds at an arbitrary $n \geq 2$. That is to say, we are of the next induction hypothesis:
\begin{equation}
\forall s \geq 0, \left(z_{1} + z_{2} + \dots + z_{n}\right)^{s} = \sum_{r_{1}+\dots +r_{n} = s}\frac{s!}{r_{1}!r_{2}!\dots r_{n}!}{z_{1}}^{r_{1}}{z_{2}}^{r_{2}}\dots{z_{n}}^{r_{n}}.
\end{equation}
Then at $n+1$, we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\left(z_{1} + z_{2} + \dots + z_{n} + z_{n+1}\right)^{r} &= \sum_{s=0}^{r}\frac{r!}{s!\left(r-s\right)!}\left(z_{1} + \dots + z_{n}\right)^{s}{z_{n+1}}^{r-s}\\
&= \sum_{s=0}^{r}\frac{r!}{s!\left(r-s\right)!}\left(\sum_{r_{1}+\dots +r_{n} = s}\frac{s!}{r_{1}!r_{2}!\dots r_{n}!}{z_{1}}^{r_{1}}{z_{2}}^{r_{2}}\dots{z_{n}}^{r_{n}}\right){z_{n+1}}^{r-s}\\
&= \sum_{s=0}^{r}\sum_{r_{1}+\dots + r_{n} = s}\frac{r!}{s!\left(r-s\right)!}\frac{s!}{r_{1}!r_{2}!\dots r_{n}!}{z_{1}}^{r_{1}}{z_{2}}^{r_{2}}\dots{z_{n}}^{r_{n}}{z_{n+1}}^{r-s}\\
&= \sum_{s=0}^{r}\sum_{r_{1}+\dots +r_{n}=s}\frac{r!}{r_{1}!r_{2}!\dots r_{n}!\left(r-s\right)!}{z_{1}}^{r_{1}}{z_{2}}^{r_{2}}\dots{z_{n}}^{r_{n}}{z_{n+1}}^{r-s}\\
&= \sum_{r_{1}+r_{2}+\dots +r_{n}+r_{n+1}=r}\frac{r!}{r_{1}!r_{2}!\dots r_{n}!r_{n+1}!}{z_{1}}^{r_{1}}{z_{2}}^{r_{2}}\dots{z_{n}}^{r_{n}}{z_{n+1}}^{r_{n+1}},
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where the induction hypothesis is used for the second equality, and a change of variable with $r_{n+1} = r - s$ is used for the last equality. As a result, we may conclude that the formula holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: This can be proved by counting combinations via the Mississippi formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the "multinomial formula".  Look it up ... for example [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)

As a proof by induction, use something like
$$
(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n+x_{n+1})^r = (y+x_{n+1})^r
$$
say, with $y=x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n$.
Use the binomial theorem for that, then use your induction  hypothesis on all the powers of $y$.

Comment: Proved the formula using your hints. I have added the proof to my post. Thanks a lot.